# What is the proper way to remove elements from a scala mutable map using a predicate

Tags: scala, scala-2.8, mutable, scala-collections

How to do that without creating any new collections? Is there something better than this?

```
val m = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, Long]("1" -> 1, "2" -> 2, "3" -> 3, "4" -> 4)
m.foreach(t => if (t._2 % 2 == 0) m.remove(t._1))
println(m)
```

P.S. in Scala 2.8

Comment: Questions about collections should say whether a 2.7 or a 2.8 answer is sought.

Comment: Using 2.8 for quite a long time, already forgot about 2.7.
Thanks, added P.S.

Comment: There's a Scala-2.8 tag you could add as an indication that this is a 2.8 specific question.

Comment: Thanks, replaced "predicate" with it

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`retain` does what you want.  In 2.7:

```
val a = collection.mutable.Map(1->"one",2->"two",3->"three")
a: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,java.lang.String] = 
  Map(2 -> two, 1 -> one, 3 -> three)

scala> a.retain((k,v) => v.length < 4)   

scala> a
res0: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,java.lang.String] =
  Map(2 -> two, 1 -> one)
```

It also works, but I think is still in flux, in 2.8.

Comment: Looks like retain is deprecated in 2.8:
http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/scala/collection/Map.html

deprecated: cannot be type inferred because of retain in Iterable.

Comment: Indeed; they might have to rename it, or come up with some other workaround.  I don't think it will just vanish; that would be kind of silly.  I'm interpreting that deprecation as "in flux, might change".

Comment: Looks like deprecation is going to be removed. So the answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Per the Scala mutable map [reference page](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/Map.html), you can remove a single element with either -= or remove, like so:

```
val m = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, Long]("1" -> 1, "2" -> 2, "3" -> 3, "4" -> 4)
m -= "1" // returns m
m.remove("2") // returns Some(2)
```

The difference is that -= returns the original map object, while remove returns an Option containing the value corresponding to the removed key (if there was one.)

Of course, as other answers indicate, if you want to remove many elements based on a condition, you should look into retain, filter, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an `immutable.Map`, in **2.7** it might have to be something like:

```
def pred(k: Int, v: String) = k % 2 == 0

m --= (m.filter(pred(_, _)).keys
```

As there is no `retain` method available. Obviously in this case `m` must be declared as a `var`

Comment: If you're using an immutable Map and hence must create a new one, it's pretty easy to simply filter with the negation of the predicate.

Comment: Indeed, this is true: it depends what you feel is more readable in a given situation

Answer (score 0):

for scala version=2.13.6 use *filterInPlace*

[doc link](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.6/scala/collection/mutable/Map.html#filterInPlace(p:(K,V)=%3EBoolean):MapOps.this.type)

```
@ val a = collection.mutable.Map(1->"one",2->"two",3->"three")
a: collection.mutable.Map[Int, String] = HashMap(
  1 -> "one",
  2 -> "two",
  3 -> "three"
)

@ a.filterInPlace((k,v) => v.length < 4)
res1: collection.mutable.Map[Int, String] = HashMap(1 -> "one", 2 -> "two")

@ a
res2: collection.mutable.Map[Int, String] = HashMap(1 -> "one", 2 -> "two")
```