# A bug of mutable.Set.foreach in scala?

Tags: scala, foreach, scala-collections, mutable

I'm using scala 2.9.1, when I try this code:

```
import scala.collection.mutable
val a = mutable.Set(1,2,3,4,7,0,98,9,8)
a.foreach(x => { println(x); a.remove(x) })
```

the result was something like

```
0
98
2
1
4
3
8
```

which did not list all the elements of a. After this, a becomes Set(9, 7) instead of empty set. It looks very weird to me, is it a bug or we just cannot modify the set itself when doing foreach?

Comment: Why the downvote? I think it's a very valid question for someone new to Iterators and how they work

Comment: I have not seen anything like that, but you could accomplish a similar result with `a.flatMap ( x => { println(x); if(cond) None else Some(x) })` which will return an new set with the `None` items removed.

Comment: Not only is it a valid question, it duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803085/iterators-for-mutable-collections-in-scala and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417994/scala-remove-in-place-all-elements-of-a-listbuffer-that-meet-a-condition and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500548/what-is-the-proper-way-to-remove-elements-from-a-scala-mutable-map-using-a-predi

Answer (score 10):

You may not modify a collection while traversing or iterating over it.

This is the same in Scala as it is in Java (and most other programming languages/libraries). Except that in Java, the `Iterator` class provides a `remove` method that can be used instead of the collection's `remove` method to remove elements while iterating using that `Iterator` (but will invalidate any other iterators of that collection that might be in use). Scala Iterators provide no such method.

Comment: `foreach` is "traversing" not "iterating".

Comment: @sepp2k nice comment, but it didn't say nothing about reason why it is outputting such a strange result (why it gives this particular result)

Comment: @xhudik It gives an unexpected result because it does something forbidden that causes unpredictable behavior. The specific result occurs because of implementation details of the HashMap class that I don't know. One thing I could imagine is that there's a hash collision and deleting one of the conflicting elements causes other elements to move into the already-iterated part of the array that backs up the hash map. So the iteration wouldn't get to those items.

Comment: @sepp2k,@user1923692 - if so, user1923692 is right - it is a bug. Unpredictable behavior(i.e. "it does something forbidden" - as you wrote) should be stopped by emitting an error or exception - correct?

Comment: @xhudik No. I mean that is what you'd expect from well-behaved languages like Java and Scala, but modifying a collection while iterating over it is explicitly documented to leave the collection in an unspecified state (at least in the Java API - I don't know where it says so in the Scala API). So if anything it's a shortcoming of the API design, not a bug in the implementation.

Comment: @sepp2k - ok, I redesign my comment: it is not a problem that scala modify the collection into unpredictable state. But the compiler should emit some warning (or exception) in order to inform a programmer that something was done wrong. Better?

Comment: @xhudik The compiler can't possibly detect that - at least not with 100% accuracy and even an acceptably accurate heuristic would be a very challenging task.

Comment: hmmm strange, so there is no way how to inform a programmer that his result might be corrupted in such situations? Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with compilers but during code optimization step (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler ) it should be detectable - i really don't know...